Is "into" a verb in this sentence?
Here's the sentence:
Yuko went out of the house and into the garden.

Have you ever heard  someone say: I into, you into, he/she/it intos... ?

Prepositional phrases can be coordinated. Consider the song:  Over the river and through the woods to grandmother's house we go.

@Mari-LouA, no. I started learning English a few months ago.

You're making wonderful progress if you only started a few months ago. Bravo! Some learners take a year or more to learn the simple past.

Your English is very impressive if you've only been studying a few months!  But this question could have been answered with a dictionary: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/into

This question is similar to: Yuko went out of the house and into the garden. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In OP's example, "into" and "out of" are prepositions.
The subject (Yuko) and verb (went) are predictably repeated elements that don't need to be explicitly specified again - but they could be...

Yuko went out of the house and Yuko went into the garden.

...OR we could "delete" only the subject, but explicitly repeat the verb...

Yuko went out of the house and went into the garden.


Thank you very much for your answer.

Can we remove "and": "Yuko went out of the house into the garden" ? If we can, does the sentence without "and" mean the same as the initial one with it? Thanks.

If you remove and, you're starting a completely new sentence, which normally requires that you include the subject and verb again, even if they're the same as in the first sentence. As to whether they "mean" the same, it depends what you "mean" by that question. It would be noticed as very unusual with or without and if you repeated both subject and verb as per my first example. So I might say what that "means" is the text came from a non-native speaker, or perhaps it's an unusual literary stylistic choice - but the literal meaning is unchanged in all cases.

As usual, only the full context will tell you what any utterance "means".

I'm bothering one thing. Where is the garden? I mean: is it necessary right near the house, i.e. the door leads immediately into the garden? Or may the garden be some distance away from the house? Because when you inserted the second "went" for the explanation, the sentence started to mean that the garden may not be next to the house. For example, Yuko went out of the house and went into the garden which was in another neighborhood. Hence in the OP's sentence, the garden may also not be near the house, right?

@Loviii: If the second instance of the "movement" verb (went, here) is "deleted" from a compound sentence, the "scale" of the two movements must be similar. Going out of the house is only a small movement, so in OP's example it must also be a small movement to go into the garden. You can't say He went out of the house and to the North Pole, for example, because one movement is a few steps, but the other is a major expedition. But you can say He went down the local pub and to the town center in the right context, because the "travel distances" are commensurate.

"From A to B" is two prepositions that don't need "and" between them. Would it be correct to say here: "Yuko went from the house to the garden."? Thanks.

Possibly. Or possibly not. We don't have the full context of OP's example to say with certainty that and is potentially redundant in that exact utterance. Obviously you can't apply the same principle and remove the conjunction and deleted subject+verb from my example He went down the local pub and [he went] to the town center**. And it might not be redundant in OP's example if it was in response to someone saying Yuko lost his car keys when he came to visit you, so we need a complete list of exactly where he went while he was with you.

"Yuko went out of the house into the garden" - Based on your comments, you consider  this sentence unnatural since it's without "and". But here another member says it's natural and explains what it means. Could you advise me please what conclusion I should draw?

@Loviii: Perhaps I haven't expressed myself well. I certainly don't think "Yuko went out of the house into the garden" is remotely unnatural. At a somewhat refined level that's probably not relevant to the average learner, it's unlikely there would be many contexts justifying the explicit coordinating conjunction "Yuko went out of the house and into the garden". But all learners should certainly be aware that full repetition of both subject and verb ("Yuko went out of the house and Yuko went into the garden") would normally be very unnatural.

OP has asked:

Is "into" a verb in this sentence?
Yuko went out of the house and into the garden.

In the clause, the repeated verb "went" is omitted. "into" cannot be a verb as it is a preposition. Please note "into" is used instead of "in".
"Gapping" is a linguistic technique that omits repeated verbs in coordinated clauses to avoid repetition.

Reference Collins dictionary:.
gapping.
in British English.
noun (in transformational grammar) a rule that deletes repetitions of a verb, as in the sentence.
Bill voted for Smith, Sam for McKay, and Dave for Harris.
Mary brought the bread, John the cheese, and Bill the wine.
.
into.
preposition.
—used as a function word to indicate entry, introduction, insertion,
superposition, or inclusion.
came into the house.
enter into an alliance

